# Php T_encapsed and whitepasce error

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I do get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Atestat\addate.php on line 51

on this line

```
else if ($_Post) { 
    if (($_POST['p_nume'] == "") || ($_POST['p_nume'] == "")) { 
    header("Location: addate.php"); 
    exit;
```

---

```
<?php 
include 'ch20_include.php'; 

if (!$_POST) {//nu se vede,arata 
 $display_block = <<<END_OF_TEXT
<form method="post" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]"> 
<fieldset> 
<legend>Prenume/Nume:</legend><br/> 
<input type="text" name="p_nume" size="30" maxlength="75" required="required" /> 
<input type="text" name="nume"   size="30" maxlength="75" required="required" /> 
</fieldset> 

<p>label for="adress">Strada:</label><br/> 
<input type="text"  id="adress" name="adress" size="30" /></p> 

<fieldset> 
<legend>Oras/Judet/Cod Postal:</legend><br/> 
<input type="text" name="oras" size="30" maxlength="50" /> 
<input type="text" name="judet" size="5" maxlength="2" /> 
<input type="text" name="cod_postal" size="10" maxlength="10" /> 
</fieldset> 

<fieldset> 
<legend>Numar de Telefon:</legend><br/> 
<input type="text" name="telefon" size="30" maxlength="25" /> 
<input type="radio" id="tel_type_h" name="tel_type" value="home" checked /> 
    <label for="tel_type_h">Acasa</label> 
<input type="radio" id="tel_type_w" name="tel_type" value="work" /> 
    <label for="tel_type_w">Elev</label> 
<input type="radio" id="tel_type_o" name="tel_type" value="altceva" /> 
    <label for="tel_type_o">Altceva</label> 
</fieldset> 

<fieldset> 
<legend>Nota-Romana:</legend><br/> 
<input type="text" name="notar_1" size="5" maxlength="50" /> 
<input type="text"  name="notar_2" size="5" maxlength="50" /> 
<input type="text"  name="notar_3" size="5" maxlength="50" /> 
<input type="text"  name="notar_4" size="5" maxlength="50" /> 
<input type="text"  name="notar_5" size="5" maxlength="50" /> 
<input type="text"  name="medier"  size="5" maxlength="50" /> 
</fieldset>  

<p><label for="nota_personala">Nota Personala:</label><br/> 
<textarea id="nota_personala" name="nota_personala" cols="35" rows="3"></textarea></p> 

<button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">Adauga Elev</button> 
</form>  
END_OF_TEXT; 
} else if ($_POST) { 
    if (($_POST['p_nume'] == "") || ($_POST['p_nume'] == "")) { 
    header("Location: addate.php"); 
    exit;
    }

    //Conectarea la bazadedate 
        doDB(); 

    $safe_p_nume = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['p_nume']); 
    $safe_nume = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['nume']); 
    $safe_adresa = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['adresa']); 
    $safe_oras = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['oras']); 
    $safe_judet = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['judet']); 
    $safe_cod_postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_Post['cod_postal']); 
    $safe_tel_numar = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['tel_numar']); 
    $safe_notab_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notab_1']); 
    $safe_notab_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notab_2']); 
    $safe_notab_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notab_3']); 
    $safe_notab_4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notab_4']); 
    $safe_notab_5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notab_5']); 
    $safe_medieb = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['medieb']); 
    $safe_notac_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notac_1']); 
    $safe_notac_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notac_2']); 
    $safe_notac_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notac_3']); 
    $safe_notac_4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notac_4']); 
    $safe_notac_5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notac_5']); 
    $safe_mediec = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['mediec']); 
    $safe_notaf_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notaf_1']); 
    $safe_notaf_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notaf_2']); 
    $safe_notaf_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notaf_3']); 
    $safe_notaf_4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notaf_4']); 
    $safe_notaf_5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notaf_5']); 
    $safe_medief = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['medief']); 
    $safe_notafr_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notafr_1']); 
    $safe_notafr_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notafr_2']); 
    $safe_notafr_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notafr_3']); 
    $safe_notafr_4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notafr_4']); 
    $safe_notafr_5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notafr_5']); 
    $safe_mediefr = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['mediefr']); 
    $safe_notag_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notag_1']); 
    $safe_notag_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notag_2']); 
    $safe_notag_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notag_3']); 
    $safe_notag_4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notag_4']); 
    $safe_notag_5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notag_5']); 
    $safe_medieg = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['medieg']); 
    $safe_notai_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notai_1']); 
    $safe_notai_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notai_2']); 
    $safe_notai_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notai_3']); 
    $safe_notai_4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notai_4']); 
    $safe_notai_5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notai_5']); 
    $safe_mediei = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['mediei']); 
    $safe_notam_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notam_1']); 
    $safe_notam_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notam_2']); 
    $safe_notam_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notam_3']); 
    $safe_notam_4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notam_4']); 
    $safe_notam_5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notam_5']); 
    $safe_mediem = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['mediem']); 
    $safe_notare_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notare_1']); 
    $safe_notare_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notare_2']); 
    $safe_notare_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notare_3']); 
    $safe_notare_4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notare_4']); 
    $safe_notare_5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notare_5']); 
    $safe_mediere = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['mediere']);
    $safe_notar_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notar_1']); 
    $safe_notar_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notar_2']); 
    $safe_notar_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notar_3']); 
    $safe_notar_4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notar_4']); 
    $safe_notar_5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['notar_5']); 
    $safe_medier = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['medier']);
    $safe_note = mysqli_real_escape_string(%mysqli,$_POST['note']); 

    //Adauga 
    $add_nume_sql = "INSERT INTO nume_principal (date_added, date_modified, p_nume, nume) VALUES(now(), now(), '".$safe_p_nume"', '".$safe_nume"')"; 
    $add_nume_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_nume_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

    if (($_POST['adress;]) || ($_POST['oras']) || ($_POST['judet']) || ($_POST['cod_postal'])) { 
    $add_adress_sql = "INSERT INTO adress (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, adresa, oras, judet, cod_postal) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(), '".$safe_adresa"', '".$safe_oras"', '".$safe_judet"', '".$safe_cod_postal"')"; 
    $add_adress_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_adress_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
    } 
    if ($_POST['tel_numar']) { 
    $add_tel_sql = "INSERT INTO telefon (nume_id. date_added, date_modified, tel_numar) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(), '".$safe_tel_numar"')"; 
    $add_tel_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_tel_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
    } 
if ($_POST['notab_1']) || ($_POST['notab_2']) || ($_POST['notab_3']) || ($_POST['notab_4']) || ($_POST['notab_5'] || ($_POST['medieb'])) { 
    $add_biologie_sql = "INSERT INTO biologie (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, notab_1, notab_2, notab_3, notab_4, notab_5, medieb) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(), '".safe_notab_1")"' ,'".$safe_notab_2"', '".$safe_notab_3"', '".$safe_notab_4"', '".$safe_notab_5"', '"$safe_medieb"')"; 
    $add_biologie_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$add_biologie_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
} 
if ($_POST['notac_1']) || ($_POST['notac_2']) || ($_POST['notac_3']) || ($_POST['notac_4']) || ($_POST['notac_5'] || ($_POST['mediec'])) { 
    $add_chimie_sql = "INSERT INTO chimie (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, notac_1, notac_2, notac_3, notac_4, notac_5, mediec) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(),  '".safe_notac_1")"' ,'".$safe_notac_2"', '".$safe_notac_3"', '".$safe_notac_4"', '".$safe_notac_5"', '"$safe_mediec"')"; 
    $add_chimie_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$add_chimie_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
} 
if ($_POST['notaf_1']) || ($_POST['notaf_2']) || ($_POST['notaf_3']) || ($_POST['notaf_4']) || ($_POST['notaf_5'] || ($_POST['medief'])) { 
    $add_fizica_sql = "INSERT INTO fizica(nume_id, date_added, date_modified, notaf_1, notaf_2, notaf_3, notaf_4, notaf_5, medief) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(),   '".safe_notaf_1")"' ,'".$safe_notaf_2"', '".$safe_notaf_3"', '".$safe_notaf_4"', '".$safe_notaf_5"', '"$safe_medief"')"; 
    $add_fizica_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$add_fizica_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
} 
if ($_POST['notafr_1']) || ($_POST['notafr_2']) || ($_POST['notafr_3']) || ($_POST['notafr_4']) || ($_POST['notafr_5'] || ($_POST['mediefr'])) { 
    $add_franceza_sql = "INSERT INTO franceza (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, notab_1, notafr_2, notafr_3, notafr_4, notafr_5, mediefr) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(),   '".safe_notafr_1")"' ,'".$safe_notafr_2"', '".$safe_notafr_3"', '".$safe_notafr_4"', '".$safe_notafr_5"', '"$safe_mediefr"')"; 
    $add_franceza_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$add_franceza_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
} 
if ($_POST['notag_1']) || ($_POST['notag_2']) || ($_POST['notag_3']) || ($_POST['notag_4']) || ($_POST['notag_5'] || ($_POST['medieg'])) { 
    $add_germana_sql = "INSERT INTO germana (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, notag_1, notag_2, notag_3, notag_4, notag_5, medieg) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(),  '".safe_notag_1")"' ,'".$safe_notag_2"', '".$safe_notag_3"', '".$safe_notag_4"', '".$safe_notag_5"', '"$safe_medieg"')"; 
    $add_germana_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$add_germana_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
} 
if ($_POST['notai_1']) || ($_POST['notai_2']) || ($_POST['notai_3']) || ($_POST['notai_4']) || ($_POST['notai_5'] || ($_POST['mediei'])) { 
    $add_informatica_sql = "INSERT INTO informatica (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, notai_1, notai_2, notai_3, notai_4, notai_5, mediei) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(),  '".safe_notai_1")"' ,'".$safe_notai_2"', '".$safe_notai_3"', '".$safe_notai_4"', '".$safe_notai_5"', '"$safe_mediei"')"; 
    $add_informatica_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$add_informatica_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
} 
if ($_POST['notam_1']) || ($_POST['notam_2']) || ($_POST['notam_3']) || ($_POST['notam_4']) || ($_POST['notam_5'] || ($_POST['mediem'])) { 
    $add_matematica_sql = "INSERT INTO matematica (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, notam_1, notam_2, notam_3, notam_4, notam_5, mediem) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(),  '".safe_notam_1")"' ,'".$safe_notam_2"', '".$safe_notam_3"', '".$safe_notam_4"', '".$safe_notam_5"', '"$safe_mediem"')"; 
    $add_matematica_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,matematica_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));  
} 
if ($_POST['notare_1']) || ($_POST['notare_2']) || ($_POST['notare_3']) || ($_POST['notare_4']) || ($_POST['notare_5'] || ($_POST['mediere'])) { 
    $add_religie_sql = "INSERT INTO religie (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, notare_1, notare_2, notare_3, notare_4, notare_5, mediere) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(),   '".safe_notare_1")"' ,'".$safe_notare_2"', '".$safe_notare_3"', '".$safe_notare_4"', '".$safe_notare_5"', '"$safe_mediere"')"; 
    $add_religie_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$add_religie_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
} 
if ($_POST['notar_1']) || ($_POST['notar_2']) || ($_POST['notar_3']) || ($_POST['notar_4']) || ($_POST['notar_5'] || ($_POST['medier'])) { 
    $add_romana_sql = "INSERT INTO romana (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, notar_1, notar_2, notar_3, notar_4, notar_5, medier) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(),  '".safe_notar_1")"' ,'".$safe_notar_2"', '".$safe_notar_3"', '".$safe_notar_4"', '".$safe_notar_5"', '"$safe_medier"')"; 
    $add_biologie_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$add_biologie_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
} 
if ($_POST['note']) { 
$add_nota_sql = "INSERT INTO nota_personala (nume_id, date_added, date_modified, note) VALUES ('".$nume_id"', now(), now(), '".$safe_note"')"; 
$add_nota_res =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_nota_sql) or die(mysql_error($mysqli)); 
} 
mysqli_close($mysqli); 
$display_block = "<p>A fost adaugat.Ai dori sa mai adaugi si <a fref=\"addata.php\">Altceva</a>?</p>"; 
    } 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head> 
<title>Adauga un Elev</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Adauga un Elev</h1> 
<?php echo $display_block; ?> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I Have posted the Code,I'm trying to do a Marks-Catalog for my school.And i'm trying to add some Notes and info's

Comment: use else if ($_POST)  in place of else if ($_Post)

Comment: it remains the same.

Comment: Which line is line 51?

Comment: Sorry, the error does not match the code you posted. I suggest you post the whole file.

Comment: The braces in the code you've posted don't have closing braces.... and `if (($_POST['p_nume'] == "") || ($_POST['p_nume'] == "")) ` seems rather meaninglessly repetitive

Comment: i have posted the code.

Comment: It's a parse error... PHP actually tells you where it is... What do we know that you don't?

Comment: It's `$_POST`, not `$_Post`.

Comment: The code i've posted it s copyied from a book,sa i don't know what is false..I've changed $_Post with $_POST and nothing changed.

Comment: Check your code for typos: `%mysqli` should be `$mysqli`, `< a fref` should be `<a href` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 49, there is a whitespace at the end of `END_OF_TEXT;` that you should remove.

The file has other typos, like in line 120, where instead of:

```
$safe_note = mysqli_real_escape_string(%mysqli,$_POST['note']);
```

should be:

```
$safe_note = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['note']);
```

And also, line 123, where semicolon should be changed by quote:

```
$_POST['adress;])
```

Comment: It's worth emphasising that heredoc and nowdoc are *extremely* pedantic about how they end, which is a very good thing but one you need to be aware of.